# Error: Unable to complete last action in Watson Studio Modeler flows

Tags: artificial-intelligence, ibm-watson, watson-studio, spss-modeler

I`m trying training a model with a little dataset (1000 rows), but Modeler flow of IBM Watson Studio takes too long time in **"Running flow Status: Training model process completed, took 4 minutes and 20 seconds"** state.

After this, result in generic error **"Error: Unable to complete last action"**
[image]

**MORE INFOS**

**Modeling**

[image]

**Dataset:**

[image]

**Type:**

[image]

**Partition**

[image]

**Neural Net Modeling**

[image]

Anybody know what the problem?